# web.config rewrite http://www.name.it to https://www.name.com

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I've searched similar question but i didn't find an answer to my specific problem.
I'm not good with regexp or rewrites so maybe what i want to do cannot be done.
I switched a site from http to https, and redirected all http requests to the relative https using the following rule, works perfectly.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I also own www.mysite.it redirected through dns to www.mysite.com.
With the actived rewrite the requests get redirected to https://www.mysite.it, i don't have an ssl certificate for that and so it fails.

I would like to redirect the
**http**://www.mysite.**it**/whatever 
requests to 
**https**://www.mysite.**com**/whatever

The only other solution i can i find is to buy an ssl for the other domain but, being only a redirect, seems like a waste of money.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could just hard code the url...

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.name.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

Comment: i would like to understand how to make a rule that intercepts only the .it requests but... thanks, you solved my problem :)